# How do I find the reflection of a line over a line?

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have two line assume one is Ray and another is a wall. So when Ray hit the wall it reflects back. I want to know the intersection point of Ray and wall and reflected line points or equation. The wall lines always perpendicular to x or y-axis.

For Example, Ray line points are `(0, 2)` and `(3, 0)`. The wall points are `(0, 0)` and `(2, 1)`. I have to convert this to a Python program. So if anybody can explain in programming (specific algorithm) way that helps me a lot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you do it with pencil and paper?

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332696/puzzle-how-many-ways-can-you-hit-a-target-with-a-laser-beam-within-four-reflect/41333099#41333099  (info about your question is mostly in the comments).

Comment: @0605002 I already did your advice. I could easily find the reflected line with pen and paper. But the problem is I couldn't find the math equation. So that I couldn't convert that to my python program. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Thank you. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: similar problem [https://stackoverflow.com/q/44318108/2521214](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322702/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

> Ray line points are (0, 2) and (3, 0)

```
(x0, y0) = (0, 2)
(x1, y1) = (3, 0)
```

So ray has parametric equation

```
x = x0 + t * (x1 - x0)  //here 0 + 3 * t
y = y0 + t * (y1 - y0)  //here 2 - 2 * t
```

Now you have to find what coordinate reaches a border first - solve equations

```
x0 + t * (x1 - x0) = xb
y0 + t * (y1 - y0) = yb
```

and get smaller value of t

Mirror point becomes new base point for parametric equations. If you meet vertical border, x-component changes its sign, y-component remains the same. If you meet horizontal border - vice versa.

Comment: Can you give me some reference link?. Or can you elaborate a little bit? I can't understand the flow.

Comment: What namely is not clear? Parametric line representation? Pseudocode for similar (without mirroring): problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758570/robotics-square-grid-intersection-point/36760730#36760730